# Why does my monitoring metrics of the Log Analytics workspace not display the server information?

Tags: azure, monitoring

I installed recently a Log Analytics agent on one of my Windows on-premise servers.
The agent has a healthy heartbeat and I am able to query logs.

I would like to visualize certain properties of the server, i.e. the available disk space, the memory, etc.
To do this I thought of using "Monitoring" - "Metrics". When I select 'Heartbeat' I get a time chart.
[image]

When I however select free space, memory consumption or anything else, it doesn't show anything.
[image]

How can I ingest/visualize the data for my server in the Metrics Explorer?